# Tensorflow: How to create new neuron (Not perceptron neuron)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So tensorflow is extremely useful at creating neural networks that involve perceptron neurons. However, if one wanted to use a new type of neuron instead of the classic perceptron neuron, is this possible through augmenting tensorflow code? I can't seem to find an answer. I understand this would change the forward propagation, and more mathematical calculations, and I am willing to change all the necessary areas.

I am also aware that I can just code from scratch the layers I need, and the neurons I had in mind, but tensorflow nevertheless has GPU integration, so one can see its more ideal to manipulate their code as opposed to creating my own from scratch.

Has anyone experimented with this? My goal is to create neural network structures that use a different type of neuron than the classic perceptron.

If someone who knows where in tensorflow I could look to see where they initialize the perceptron neurons, I would very much appreciate it!

Edit:

To be more specific, is it possible to alter code in tensorflow to use a different neuron type rather than the perceptron to invoke the tensorlfow Module: tf.layers for example? Or tf.nn? (conv2D, batch-norm, max-pool, etc). I can figure out the details. I just need to know where (I'm sure they're a few locations) I would go about changing code for this.

Comment: This is too vague, and yes, you can definitely do whatever neuron implementation you want in TF, but your question is too vague as you don't really specify exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, here is an example; I would like to be able to use the tensorflow Module: tf.Layers. But with a new type of neuron instead of the pereptron neuron. The reason my question is not incredibly specific is because what I want applies across the whole library, rather than just a single example.

Comment: Made edits, to the question.

Comment: I very much doubt that the concept of a "neuron" exists anywhere in the Tensorflow code base. Tensorflow manipulates tensors. It uses methods such as dot products or convolutions to do this. Neurons in this context are just abstractions that make it easier to think about this stuff. I also find it hard to understand what you're trying to do without having a concrete example.

Comment: Ah okay, possibly useful information. I'll dig around more and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if one wanted to use a new type of neuron instead of the classic perceptron neuron, is this possible through augmenting tensorflow code?

**Yes.** Tensorflow provides you the possibility to define a computational graph. It then can automatically calculate the gradient for that. No need to do it yourself. This is the reason why you define it symbolically. You might want to read the [whitepaper](https://www.tensorflow.org/about/bib) or start with a tutorial.